# Why are the RSpec tests placed within the `module` keyword?

Tags: ruby, rspec

First, I'm not attempting to test a module. I'm testing classes within a single module. [This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205352/testing-a-class-inside-of-a-module-with-rspec) doesn't describe the code I'm looking at, so it's tough to draw parallels to my curiosity.

I'm following along [with this tutorial](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/creating-a-tic-tac-toe-game-with-ruby/), which is outdated; However, it's a suggested resource.

My specific question is:

Why is the RSpec language in the spec file placed within the `module TicTacToe`, like so:

```rb
require 'some_file'

module TicTacToe
  #RSpec examples here
end
```

I'm very new to RSpec and coding in general, so I'm not familiar with the conventions of writing tests in RSpec; Is this organization necessary? Out-dated? My tests are passing and things are working as expected; I'm just attempting to learn how to write tests, and most specs begin with `RSpec.describe Foo do` or `describe Bar do`

Comment: I think it's just used as a namespace here, for the sake of keeping things organized. The tutorial says `The Cell class is wrapped in a TicTacToe module to follow Ruby gem conventions and prevent class name collisions when gems are included in other projects. `.  So you actually could remove all references to this module and it would work the same

Comment: I understand the use of the TicTacToe module in the context of the gem code. My question is directed at the use of the TicTacToe module in the spec file, being used to contain the example groups. Unless you're implying the same namespacing convention can be applied to spec files...

Comment: Yeah, I think it applies to the spec file too. It's not actually giving any functionality there. Just namespacing.

Comment: That's more concrete info then I've been able to find RE the use of the module keyword in a spec file, so thanks! Put that in a proper answer, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen `module` used like that within spec files. I suspect that's a very old tutorial. (Wordpress helpfully shows it's from Oct 25, but neglects to mention which year. But the oldest comment is from 2014)

I recommend you find a more recent tutorial.

The `describe` keyword would be more appropriate here. Most of the specs I work with looked like this a few years ago:

```
RSpec.describe TicTacToe::SomeClass, type: :model do
  #RSpec examples here
end
```

Or even more modern, rspec discerns the type (model, controller, etc.) from the path to the spec file:

```
# spec/model/tic_tac_toe/cell.rb

describe Cell do
  let(:first_cell) { described_class.new }
  #RSpec examples here
end
```

Comment: I'm using this tutorial with the knowledge that it's outdated; Helps hone research skills and critiquing ability. Your answer helps by illustrating how to organize the start of the Example Group to include the module name and class being described. Thanks for the answer.